# How to record and replay the `center frequency` when `file_sink`?

Tags: gnuradio, frequency, signal-identification, usrp

Workflow as below:

[image]
When `file_source` after `file_sink`,`center frequency` is not recorded and replay in `gui_sink`.

[image]

How to record and replay the `center frequency` when `file_sink`?

Comment: The file sink actually has nothing to do with this. You get the exact same problem if you just wire the USRP source directly to the GUI sink. It's because you didn't set the center frequency on the GUI sink

Comment: Even you set the center frequency,file sink doesn't record it.That's the key problem.

Comment: Type in the same center frequency when you load the file?

Comment: @user253751,I will not ask this question if I can remember hundreds frequencies per hour.

Comment: You've got a fundamental misunderstanding what the file sink or source do. They just deal with the raw time samples. "Frequency" is not among the things they save. As @user253751 says, this isn't special about these sinks either: sample flows are just that, samples. There's no "interpretation" like "this is at frequency XYZ" inherent to these sample flows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all. The file sink, as any sample-processing block in GNU Radio, is not aware of RF properties – all it sees are the baseband samples. So, the representation of things being centered around 0 Hz is *correct*; that's all the information there is in the signal.

You will need some other mechanism to save such information. SigMF is one option, filenames another, or a metadata file sink combined with adding the necessary tags yourself.